# Android Studio does not have write access

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using android studio 3.4.2. When I try to update
the android studio it says

"Studio does not have write access to /app/extra. Please Run it by a privileged user to update"

How to solve it?

[image]

Comment: Run it as administrator

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Navigate to your Android studio folder via terminal then run android studio with administrator privileges, using sudo or su. If you provide more  information, like which OS you are using, maybe I'll be able to tell you the exactly command line you should use.

Edit:

1. Open terminal application, then type de following :
   `cd ~/android-studio/bin` *
2. Now we must run Android Studio script file studio.sh as administrator:

`sudo ./studio.sh`

If doesn't work try : `sudo sh studio.sh`

3. (Optional) To prevent this problem every time you want update android studio, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37704528/8513494

And is it.

- I'm assuming that your android studio is located on your user folder, if there's a problem with this step, you should check `/opt/` directory and look out for android studio installation folder or see https://superuser.com/a/1080329

Comment: Thanks, Daniel, I am using Linux Mint 19.2

Comment: Rahed, I already edited the answer, tell me if there is any problem.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel for your guidance. It's working fine now.

Comment: You are welcome Mir Rashid Uddin, thanks for the upvote. If it doesn't bother,  please consider mark the answer as the correct answer.

Answer (score 38):

I would suggest to set your current user as owner of `/usr/bin/android-studio`

This will resolve the issue in long term:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /usr/bin/android-studio
```

Comment: in my case android studio is installet in opt dir so I had to use `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /opt/android-studio-2021.1.1` and `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /opt/android-studio`

Answer (score 25):

I would suggest setting up your current user as the owner of **Android Studio**

## Linux

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /usr/bin/android-studio
```

## Mac

```
sudo chown -R $USER /Applications/Android\ Studio.app
```

or if you using android studio portable then you can use custom path like this.

```
sudo chown -R $USER: pathDirOfYourAndroidStudio/Android\ Studio\ Preview.app
```

Comment: Perfect answer for MAC users. Worked in one go.

Comment: Nice hat trick ;)

Answer (score 8):

For linux mint 20:

`sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /opt/android-studio-4.2/android-studio/`

Answer (score 5):

Happens on Mac when you do not have Android studio in `/Application` directory. Move it there, if it is not resolved, try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62083162/311865).

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Set access to Read and Write (default is Read only)

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest changing the owner of the android-studio directory, doing so depends on the path of your android studio. Here is mine

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /opt/android-studio
```

But you might have the following path

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /usr/bin/android-studio
```

Check well and enjoy

Answer (score 2):

If you are a MAC user and running portable AS then the simple solution is to move the application within Application folder. Check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=15OLD22wDzE). It solves my issue after wasting 3 hrs within the terminal but nothing is wasting of time. I am running MACOS 13(Ventura) & AS Electric Ele.